# Accessing env variables inside webpack AngularJS project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, environment-variables, webpack

I have an AngularJS project that uses webpack for bundling, serving, and building - no task runner such as  bower or gulp is used. I'd like to be able to set environment variables for things such as the REST API endpoints that I'll be consuming in local versus production, and then access those within my actual AngularJS project files, particularly inside controllers. What's the best way to define and pass these env variables into the project?

Comment: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin

Comment: Awesome, that did it, thanks.

Comment: Can you move that as an answer and accept it? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution was to use Webpack's definePlugin to define free/global variables:

webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    VERSION: JSON.stringify("5fa3b9"),
    BROWSER_SUPPORTS_HTML5: true,
    TWO: "1+1",
    "typeof window": JSON.stringify("object")
})
```

Comment: How do you use this inside your code? It's just global using like`window.VERSION` is in the browser?

Comment: They are used like if were macros in C, webpack replaces every occurrence with the value

Comment: @dvdvck Actually gave the missing second part of the accepted answer.  Cause I searched for the globals and there are none in the runtime browser client.  thx.