# Angular application API URL configuration with Webpack for dev and production builds

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I have an Angular app with the following simple config file `config.js`:

```
export default function(app) {
  app.constant('config', {apiUrl: 'https://localhost:8080'});
};
```

which is imported by Webpack entry point `app.js`:

```
import config from './config';
config(app);
```

I'd like to have a different `apiUrl` when I do production build.

What's the easiest way to do it in Webpack?

Comment: I don't have the exact answer as I don't use webpack.  I'm stuck using ASP.NET bundling at the moment, but the way we achieve the same thing (for our API endpoint) is to bundle a different file that defines the same constant (different values), depending on our target environment, e.g. production -> prod/config.js; uat -> uat/config.js.

Comment: Yes, this was one of the options, before I decided to have one file with `switch` on `location.hostname`

Comment: Check out my solution on Github, I can't believe how hard it seems to be to find a simple solution for passing Configurations from webpack cmd to Angular2 Typescript, my solution is very simple, https://github.com/Sweetog/yet-another-angular2-boilerplate

Answer (score 2):

There is a similiar question on https://stackoverflow.com/a/34032050/1610981

It relates you can use http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin

The config.js file would be this:

```
export default function(app) {
  app.constant('config', {apiUrl: API_URL});
};
```

And inside of webpack config files:

```
plugins:[
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    API_URL: JSON.stringify('https://localhost:8080')
  })
]
```

You should have two webpack configs, one for develoment and another for production. Each one defines API_URL macro, according with the built performed.

Comment: I have several production builds for staging also.  How do I solve it with the approach use suggested?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend use environment variable with [webpack.DefinePlugin](http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin)

```
//webpack.config.js
...

let API_URL;
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development') {
  API_URL = 'https://dev:8080';
} else {
  API_URL = 'https://prod:8080';
}

// or

const API_URL = process.env.API_URL;

...

plugins:[
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({API_URL: API_URL})
]
...
```

If **NODE_ENV** not setuped use `export NODE_ENV=development` for linux/osx or `SET NODE_ENV=development` for windows.