# How to set different constants in angularjs app for prod / dev in webpack

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I'd like to set a different url for an external api in an angularjs app depending on whether I am running in dev or prod mode:

a sketch of my app.js:

```
var API_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/api';  # dev config

...

app.constant("API_URL", API_URL)
```

I use webpack to locally serve the app on localhost:3000, and I also use it to build a prod version of the app (minified, etc) which consumes the api from a different location.

I was wondering if there is some way to configure the build process to set API_URL in the above to the desired production value:, ie:

```
    var API_URL = 'http://app.example.com/api';  # prod config?
```

?

Answer (score 0):

As answered in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33922193/5490505), you can solve this problem using Webpack's definePlugin to define environment variables:

[webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin](http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin)